# Differences between compiled code and ghci in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
-- defined externally in a module that compiles just fine
-- normal :: (RandomGen g, Random r, Floating r, Ord r) => r -> r -> g -> (r, g)
-- poisson :: (RandomGen g, Random r, Floating r, Ord r) => r -> g -> (Integer, g)
-- binomial :: (RandomGen g, Random r, Floating r, Ord r) => r -> g -> (Bool, g)
data Foobar = Foobar { n :: Double, p :: Integer, b :: Bool } deriving (Show)

randomFoobar :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Foobar, g)
randomFoobar g0 = let (n, g1) = normal 10.0 1.0 g0
                      (p, g2) = poisson 5.5 g1
                      (b, g3) = binomial 0.5 g2
                  in (Foobar n p b, g3)
```

When I try to compile this, I get a host of errors, starting with

```
Foobar.hs:8:33: error:
    • Could not deduce (Random r0) arising from a use of ‘poisson’
      from the context: RandomGen g
        bound by the type signature for:
                   randomFoobar :: forall g. RandomGen g => g -> (Foobar, g)
        at Foobar.hs:6:1-49
      The type variable ‘r0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Random Integer -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
        instance Random Bool -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
        instance Random Char -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
        ...plus four others
        ...plus 29 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: poisson 5.5 g1
      In a pattern binding: (p, g2) = poisson 5.5 g1
      In the expression:
        let
          (n, g1) = normal 10.0 1.0 g0
          (p, g2) = poisson 5.5 g1
          (b, g3) = binomial 0.5 g2
        in (Foobar n p b, g3)
```

When I type the my `randomFoobar` function directly into ghci, it works fine.

I'm very new to Haskell, and completely flumoxed by this - anyone know what is going on here?  Why is ghci different than the compiler here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHCi enables the ExtendedDefaultRules extension by default, which causes a default type to be chosen for some ambiguous types instead of just throwing an error. To make your code work everywhere, the best solution is to add a type annotation that makes the type unambiguous. The ambiguity in this case is that numeric literals are polymorphic. `5.5` could be a `Float`, a `Double`, a `Rational`, etc. Since at the end you just get a `Bool`, type inference isn't able to figure out which one you want, since any would be valid. Using `(5.5 :: Double)` instead of just `5.5` will do it, assuming `Double` is the type you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been tearing my hair out over this for a day now! :-)